# Plot a disc in Matlab, color varying with angle

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to represent some data depending on the angle of measure. I have something like that:

```
angle=[0 90 180 270 360];
value=[1 2 3 4];
```

In my case, `length(angle)=73`

How can I plot a disc in which the color of the radius line varies according to the vector value.

I would like something like imagesc but in a disc.

I unsuccessfully tried using rose, but it is limited to a max of 20 angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another alternative that does not use 3D graphics, only 2D. It uses the primitive `patch` command that draws triangles. Here is a result:

[image]

```
function PlotDisc
    thetas=(0:5:360)'*pi/180;
%     r=(0:0.1:1)';
    r = 1;
    [x,y]=pol2cart(thetas,r);
    colMap = GetColMap();
    for i=1:numel(x)-1
        X = [0 x(i) x(i+1) 0];
        Y = [0 y(i) y(i+1) 0];
        col = i / (numel(x)-1) * numel(colMap);
        patch(X,Y,col,'EdgeAlpha',0);
    end
    axis equal
end

function colMap = GetColMap()
   colMap = ...
   [0.0417         0         0
    0.0833         0         0
    0.1250         0         0
    0.1667         0         0
    0.2083         0         0
    0.2500         0         0
    0.2917         0         0
    0.3333         0         0
    0.3750         0         0
    0.4167         0         0
    0.4583         0         0
    0.5000         0         0
    0.5417         0         0
    0.5833         0         0
    0.6250         0         0
    0.6667         0         0
    0.7083         0         0
    0.7500         0         0
    0.7917         0         0
    0.8333         0         0
    0.8750         0         0
    0.9167         0         0
    0.9583         0         0
    1.0000         0         0
    1.0000    0.0417         0
    1.0000    0.0833         0
    1.0000    0.1250         0
    1.0000    0.1667         0
    1.0000    0.2083         0
    1.0000    0.2500         0
    1.0000    0.2917         0
    1.0000    0.3333         0
    1.0000    0.3750         0
    1.0000    0.4167         0
    1.0000    0.4583         0
    1.0000    0.5000         0
    1.0000    0.5417         0
    1.0000    0.5833         0
    1.0000    0.6250         0
    1.0000    0.6667         0
    1.0000    0.7083         0
    1.0000    0.7500         0
    1.0000    0.7917         0
    1.0000    0.8333         0
    1.0000    0.8750         0
    1.0000    0.9167         0
    1.0000    0.9583         0
    1.0000    1.0000         0
    1.0000    1.0000    0.0625
    1.0000    1.0000    0.1250
    1.0000    1.0000    0.1875
    1.0000    1.0000    0.2500
    1.0000    1.0000    0.3125
    1.0000    1.0000    0.3750
    1.0000    1.0000    0.4375
    1.0000    1.0000    0.5000
    1.0000    1.0000    0.5625
    1.0000    1.0000    0.6250
    1.0000    1.0000    0.6875
    1.0000    1.0000    0.7500
    1.0000    1.0000    0.8125
    1.0000    1.0000    0.8750
    1.0000    1.0000    0.9375
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000] ;  

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I had to plot polar data and looked for something similar. I do not know if it corresponds to your needs but I adapted my solution to your problem, here it is:

```
theta=(0:360)'*pi/180;
r=(0:0.1:1)';
value=repmat([360 (1:360)],size(r,1),1);
[THETA,R]=meshgrid(theta,r);
[X,Y]=pol2cart(THETA,R);
surf(X,Y,value,'edgecolor','none');
view(0,90);
```

**UPDATE**: You are absolutely right Andrey, and I suspect the 3D graphics to take more memory and thus display a lot slower but at the time I did not find any ohter way. Your solution is better, I will use it from now. The only thing I would change is the `for` loop:

```
r=1;
dtheta=0.01;
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,100)';
n=numel(theta);
[x,y]=pol2cart(theta,r);
figure;
cmap=colormap(jet);
X=[zeros(1,n-1);x(1:end-1)';x(2:end)';zeros(1,n-1)];
Y=[zeros(1,n-1);y(1:end-1)';y(2:end)';zeros(1,n-1)];
C=numel(cmap)*(1:n-1)/n-1;
patch(X,Y,C,'EdgeAlpha',0);
axis equal;
```

Comment: +1 - Looks very nice! But it is a 3D graphics. Might be problematic for some uses.

Comment: That is, when you rotate the image, you see "stairs" effect.